# Can't find error in simple dice game

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, dice

I've written this piece of code, compiled and ran.
The error tells me Array out of bounds even though I can't find where this out of bounds would occur. Also, any suggestions on improving the code so far?
(I've compiled the following booleans just to use in a later stage so don't mind them.)

```
static boolean threeOfAKind;
static boolean fourOfAKind;

public static int[] newTurn()
{
    int[] rolls=new int[5];
    for (int counter=0 ; counter<5 ; counter++)//we throw 5 dices
    {
        rolls[counter]=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        if (rolls[counter]>=7){counter--;}
        //Math.random()*6 could give result of 6 or (1*6) so the 1 added could get to 7
    }
    Arrays.sort(rolls); //makes it easier to display and to check for similar values
    return rolls;
}

public static int checkThreeOfAKind(int[] turn)
{
    int ifTrue=0;
    //while doing a 'for' loop, using the counter to 'scan' the array
    for (int counter=0 ; counter>(turn.length-2)&&ifTrue!=1;counter++)//-2 because if 3rd dice doesn't equal 4th, it's impossible to have 3 of a kind with 5 dices
    {
        if (turn[counter]==turn[counter+1]&&turn[counter+1]==turn[counter+2])
        {
            ifTrue=1;
        }
    }
    return ifTrue;
}

public static int checkFourOfAKind(int[] turn)
{
    int ifTrue=0;
    //while doing a 'for' loop, using the counter to 'scan' the array
    for (int counter=0 ; counter>(turn.length-3)&&ifTrue!=1;counter++)//see note 3 of a kind
    {
        if (turn[counter]==turn[counter+1]&&turn[counter+1]==turn[counter+2]&&turn[counter+2]==turn[counter+3])
        {
            ifTrue=1;
        }
    }
    return ifTrue;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{       
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] turn=newTurn();//puts the results of the throw in an array
    if (checkThreeOfAKind(turn)==1){threeOfAKind=true;}
    if (checkFourOfAKind(turn)==1){fourOfAKind=true;}
    System.out.println("Thown dices:\n"+turn[0]+", "+turn[1]+", "+turn[2]+", "+turn[3]+", "+turn[4]+", "+turn[5]);
    if (fourOfAKind=true){System.out.println("Four of a kind!");}
    if (threeOfAKind=true){System.out.println("Three of a kind!");}
    //error originates from above line
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: What IDE are you using? Usually it tells you the line number so you should know exactly where the error is

Comment: eclipse, says line 62, which is strange because the fourOfAKind would run before ThreeofAKind and that gave no errors

Comment: Could you label that line? a) I'm lazy b) Other users might have better things to do with their lives than count lines of code.

Comment: `counter>(turn.length-2)` your loop condition look if you swapped the `<` with `>`

Comment: ty Kevin for the counter issue, didn't solve the array but would've given me a wrong result for the 3/4 of a kind

Comment: You're trying to print out `turn[0]` to `turn[5]` -- that is six elements of your five-element array. There is no `turn[5]`.

Comment: Thank you khelwood! That was indeed the issue!

Answer (score 2):

Your function `newTurn()` returns `rolls` which is defined as

```
int[] rolls=new int[5];
```

And in `main()` you wrote:

```
int[] turn=newTurn();
```

So, `turn` is now referencing an array of length `5`, which is indexed from `0` to `4`.

But in the

```
System.out.println("Thown dices:\n"+turn[0]+".... +turn[5]);
```

You are trying to access `turn[5]` which will definitely cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.